# Given a hyperbola, determine whether any of its points lie within $\{x\in [0,1]\mid 0\leq y\leq 1\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, algorithms, conic-sections, hyperbolic-geometry

Given 
$$
y=\frac{c_1 +c_2x}{c_3+c_4x}
$$

Is there any test using the values of $c$ to see if between $x\in[0,1]$ there is at least one point where $y\in[0,1]$ *other than* just evaluating the function on the interval?

Examples could include using the distance between the hyperbola points or shifting the hyperbola.

Comment: Interesting way to write $y\leq 0$. :D

Comment: @batominovski I've encountered that way many times written by $3 $ rd level students - it may come from some remote country.

Comment: But in the body of the question, it is made clear that what is meant is $0 \le y \le 1$.

Comment: I made a mistake because I typed it up on my phone. No I am not from a remote country haha

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can easily manipulate the above formula to get an expression of the form $$y=A+\frac{B}{x+C}$$
What does this expression tells you? You can compare with $y=1/x$ hyperbola. The $C$ value just changes the vertical asymptote. The $A$ value just changes the horizontal asymptote. $B$ is a stretching factor in the vertical direction. Note that if $B<0$, you flip the hyperbola upside-down.

What you need to do is to calculate $y$ when $x=0$ and $x=1$, and calculate $x$ when $y=0$ or $y=1$. If none of these four points verify your requirements, there are no other options.